# TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ts-node

Below if I import `Entity` I get the posts's subject error (TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined), but if I replace the import with the actual `Entity` declaration the code runs fine.

[Stackblitz demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ztvxdz?file=Customer.ts).

This is `Customer.ts` in the form that produces the error when I run the code with `ts-node`:

index.ts

```
export { Customer } from "./Customer";
export { Entity } from "./Entity";
```

Customer.ts

```
import { Entity } from "./index";

export class Customer extends Entity {
  sku: string;
  constructor(po: any) {
    super();
    this.sku = po.sku;
  }
}
```

Entity.ts

```
export abstract class Entity {
  id?: string;
}
```

Run.ts (The test code)

```
import {Customer} from "./";

let c = new Customer({
  name: "Bob"
});
console.log(c);
```

If I replace the `Entity` import with the declaration like this:

```
export abstract class Entity {
  id?: string;
}    

export class Customer extends Entity {
  sku: string;
  constructor(po: any) {
    super();
    this.sku = po.sku;
  }
}
```

Then `Run.ts` logs this:

```
Customer { sku: undefined }
```

In other words it runs fine and produces no errors.  Thoughts?

Comment: maybe you wrote `Entity` path wrong?, can you provide paths too?

Comment: Circular imports causing execution to proceed past an `import` statement even though the target isn't yet loaded?

Comment: Hold the press!  I think you guys figured it out.  I have an `index.ts` at the same root as the other files.  I'm reexporting everything from that file, so I have a central place to import from.  That's what's causing it.

Comment: Double checked it.  If I import `Entity` directly from `Entity.ts` there's no problem, but if I import it from `index.ts` the exception is thrown.  I find this a bit strange?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As I suspected, your original program has circular imports.  `Run.ts` imports `index.ts`, which imports `Customer.ts`, which imports `index.ts` again.  Since `index.ts` is already in the process of loading and itself depends on `Customer.ts`, the `import { Entity } from "./index";` just binds the `Entity` of `index.ts` (which is not set yet) to the `Entity` of `Customer.ts`, and execution proceeds even though `index.ts` isn't finished loading.  Then `Entity` is undefined at the time you try to extend it.  You might argue that a circular import should be an error or that JavaScript engines should use some other algorithm that correctly handles your scenario; I'm not qualified to comment on why the current design was chosen.  (Others feel free to add information about this.)

As you saw, changing `Customer.ts` to import from `./Entity` directly instead of `./index` breaks the cycle, and everything works as expected.  Another solution would be to reverse the order of imports in `index.ts`.

Comment: Excellent observation!  I reported it as a bug just in case it can help Typescript design better handling / error reporting for this scenario.

Comment: Perhaps the compiler could detect the circular dependency, and just replace the `./` path with `./Entity`.  They are equivalent, and since it's runtime code everyone is happy  ...

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly an answer to the example above, but I got the same error message when I had Vue and Parcel, and this kind of code:

```
class Proxy {}

class MyProxy extends Proxy {}
```

After some lengthy debugging, it turned out that there seems to be some class name conflict with the name "Proxy", maybe from Parcel. After I renamed the super class as "AbstractProxy" or anything else than "Proxy", it started to work.

Answer (score -6):

You can try this command and check the application:

1. `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --force`
2. `npm install`
3. `ng serve -o`