# Why do I get an 'instanceof' is not an object error when publishing a graph?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, metabase

I try to publish the graph made with Metabase into my Vue.js, by using the code provided by Metabase. However, I keep getting this kind of error:

**ERROR**

> TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
> at Function.create ()
> at Object.inherits (inherits_browser.js:6:31)
> at eval (data-stream.js:39:1)
> at ./node_modules/jws/lib/data-stream.js (chunk-vendors.js:2033:1)
> at **webpack_require** (app.js:279:33)
> at fn (app.js:525:21)
> at eval (sign-stream.js:3:1)
> at ./node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js (chunk-vendors.js:2043:1)
> at **webpack_require** (app.js:279:33)
> at fn (app.js:525:21)

**RewardCharts.vue**

```
<template>
    <h1>Reward Points Charts</h1>
    <iframe
    src="{{url}}"
    frameborder="0"
    width="800"
    height="600"
    allowtransparency
    ></iframe>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
          return {
            url: ''
          }
        },
        created() {
            try {
                var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
                var METABASE_SITE_URL = "http://localhost:3000";
                var METABASE_SECRET_KEY = "#secret key from Metabase ";
                var payload = {
                  resource: { question: 2 },
                  exp: Math.round(Date.now() / 1000) + (10 * 60) // 10 minute expiration
                };
              const token = jwt.sign(payload, METABASE_SECRET_KEY);
              this.url = METABASE_SITE_URL + "/embed/question/" + token +  "#bordered=true&titled=true";
            } catch (e) {
              console.log(e)
            }
       }
};
</script>
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "nse-driver-points-collection",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build  --port 810",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.5",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "epic-spinners": "^2.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-axios": "^3.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See this answer to this question, which has the same error that you are experiencing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53122751/typeerror-object-prototype-may-only-be-an-object-or-null-undefined/53123468#53123468

Comment: base on what i see, the 'jsonwebtoken' cannot provide the token to be store in "jwt" even though I already install the package. I use the code provided by the metabase, im stuck on my next step.

Comment: The answer I referenced says that you probably have a circular import somewhere. You didn't post your entire codebase (and you shouldn't), but I can't see what your circular imports are based on the small amount of code that you posted. Your issue probably has nothing to do with the metabase code. Please read the linked answer carefully and see if you can find a similar situation in your codebase.